# Как указать phpstorm путь к php.ini?

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

Настраиваю xdebug. Phpinfo видит xdebug, а phpstorm - нет. Видимо потому, что читает php-cli.ini а не php.ini.

[image]
[image]

Как указать для phpstorm php.ini?

Comment: [указать в опции `-c` или переменной окружения PHPRC](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

1. Нужно создать конфиг запуска. Для этого: `Create Run Configuration -> App`
2. Добавить путь к `php.ini` в [command line/interpreter options](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php)